# Time since previous order

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, google-spreadsheets

I need to go through a big amount of data for the last 2 years in a company and calculated the time since previous orders for Users who have made multiple purchases. Which Excel function can be used for it? User ID, date etc. data is available

Comment: Could you provide a sample here?

Answer (score 0):

Both Excel and Google Sheets have a `MAXIFS()` function that can extract the latest date from one column based on matching user ids in another column.

---

[Excel help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883)

[Google Sheets help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013817?hl=en)

---

The format for the function is the same in both programs.

```
MAXIFS(max_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)
```

It sounds like you would want something like this:

```
MAXIFS([column with dates], [column with user ids], [cell with user id for this row])
```

That would give you the latest date for the current user. You can then use that to calculate time since previous order. I presume it would look like this:

```
=[cell with date for this row] - MAXIFS([column with dates], [column with user ids], [cell with user id for this row])
```

Comment: Also to get your requirement of users with multiple orders, use `COUNTIFS()` to get the count of how many orders where placed. This can be then be filtered, or put into a pivot table.